# scrolling jquery plugin

Tags: jquery, css, animation, plugins

Is there any jquery plugin that when you scroll down the items fade-in with animations ? and also to load some of the images when I scroll donwn . Or is there any tutorial to do it manually when I scroll down the item fade in or the chart shows with a transition animation ?

Comment: what you want like twitter ...........?

Comment: very vague question. please see my answer for some simple plugins that may help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For ajax loading when scrolling use.

Paul Irish's infinite scroll

http://www.infinite-scroll.com/

---

For scrolling to a position in a page use
Ariel Flesler's ScrollTo plugin.

Really usefull for animating and scrolling and is well documented.
http://flesler.blogspot.co.uk/2007/10/jqueryscrollto.html

Answer (score 0):

This may help you out. 
http://jqueryui.com/slider/#side-scroll

As well you can find detailed docs at

http://learn.jquery.com/jquery-ui/getting-started